# Create array with count of array events in R

Tags: r, subset

It seems pretty basic... but I'm trying to generate a second array in R that would correspond to the counts of the events of my primary array. For instance, if there are 14 Age[x] that are 42, I would want Age.count[x] to equal 14.

So if Age was `[1] 10 14 14 13 14 12 10` I would want my Age.count to be `[1] 2 3 3 1 3 1 2`. It seems like it should be really simple but I haven't managed yet...

My best shot so far:

```r
for (val in length(Age)) {
  Age.count[val] <- length(subset(Age, Age==val2))
}
```

Unfortunately it's giving me NA values on all but the first and last values.  Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use `ave`, i.e.,

```
> ave(age,age,FUN = length)
[1] 2 3 3 1 3 1 2
```

**DATA**

```
age <- c(10, 14, 14, 13, 14, 12, 10)
```

Comment: Oooooh perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
Age = c(10, 14, 14, 13, 14, 12, 10)
X = data.frame(Age)
Test = as.data.frame(table(X)) 
Test$X = as.numeric(as.character(Test$X))
colnames(Test) = c("Age", "Frequency")
```

Then

```
Result = dplyr::inner_join(X, Test)
```

will work.

Comment: `Error: 'by' required, because the data sources have no common variables
Run 'rlang::last_error()' to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: You are correct. The join variable in the table is formatted as factor, I will modify my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it more compact than this, but at least you can see what is happening this way.

```
age = c(10, 14, 14, 13, 14, 12, 10)
counts = table(age)

i = match(age, names(counts))
counts[i]
```

```
> counts[i]
age
10 14 14 13 14 12 10 
 2  3  3  1  3  1  2
```

Comment: Ah I think this is what I need.  Thanks!